# How to change background color using a class to target the ID of a control

Tags: jquery, asp.net

```
<asp:TextBox ReadOnly="true" ID="tbPhone" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" CssClass="tbStyle changeUpdate" Text=""></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ReadOnly="true" ID="tbFax" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" CssClass="tbStyle changeUpdate" Text=""></asp:TextBox>

$('#tbPhone, #tbFax').keypress(function() { //works
    this.style.backgroundColor = "#BCFFB9";
});
```

I will have a lot of textboxes and wanted to use a class for each textbox, get the ID and set the background color. This will ensure I can use a few lines of code for all the textboxes, regardless of the number.

So i tried this:

```
$(".changeUpdate").keypress(function() {
    $(this).attr("id").style.backgroundColor = "#BCFFB9";
});
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
0x800a138f - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to set value of the property 'backgroundColor': object is null or undefined
```

How can I resolve my issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are kind of mixing Javascript and jQuery syntaxes, try this:

```
$(".changeUpdate").keypress(function() {
    //$(this).attr("id").style.backgroundColor = "#BCFFB9";
    $(this).css("background-color","#BCFFB9");
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the correction. I knew I was missing something.

Answer (score 1):

You are not correctly selecting the elements with the class 'changeUpdate' with your code. `$(this).attr("id")` gets the id of the element, but does not select it, which is why there is an undefined reference error.

Use:

```
// when the keypress event happens on an element with class changeUpdate
$('.changeUpdate').keypress(function () {

   // Select all elements with class changeUpdate and change the css attribute 'background-color' to the color specified
   $('.changeUpdate').css('background-color', '#BCFFB9');
});
```

or use `$(this).css('background-color', '#BCFFB9');` to change the background color for just the element with the keypress.